# Is it possible in Java to add one value of an Enum to an Arraylist a number of times based on another value in the Enum?

Tags: java, arrays, list, enums

```
public enum Fruits{

APPLE(1, 1,"Apple"),
ORANGE(2, 4, "Orange"),
PEAR(3, 7, "Pear");

 private int fruitId, amount;
 private String name;

private Fruits(int fruitId, int amount, String name) {

            this.fruitId= fruitId;
            this.amount= amount;
            this.name= name;

        }
}
```

Basically I am wondering if it is possible to create an Array list of the "fruitId" value for each Enum entry, adding the fruitId to the list equal to the amount number. For example, for the ORANGE it would the number 2 to the list 4 times. If it is possible, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple, nested for-loop that first iterates over the value of the `Fruits` enum, and then over each value's `amount`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Fruits fruit : Fruits.values()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fruit.getAmount(); i++) {
        list.add(fruit.getFruitId());
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have created the valid getter methods for each field.

---

A stream approach would look like the following:

```
Arrays.stream(Fruits.values())
      .flatMap(fruit -> Stream.generate(() -> fruit.getFruitId()).limit(fruit.getAmount()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```